# Arrow destination a little above node.east

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I'm trying to get an arrow to end up slightly above/below a `node.east` marker. I tried using the `calc tikzlibrary` but for some reason, shifting the arrow's destination only works if I both `x` and `y` coordinates are non null.

My goal is to be able to distinguish the arrows arriving at and leaving node `(b)`.

What's wrong with this MWE?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, start chain = going below]

  \node[on chain] (a) {a};
  \node[on chain] (b) {b};
  \node[on chain] (c) {c};

  \node[anchor=west] at ($(a)!0.5!(b) + (0:1) $) (d) {d};
  \node[anchor=west] at ($(b)!0.5!(c) + (0:1) $) (e) {e};

  \draw[->] (a.east) -| (d.north);
  \draw[->] (d.south) |- ($(b.east) - (0.5:0)$);
  \draw[->] ($(b.east) + (0.5:0)$) -| (e.north);
  \draw[->] (e.south) |- (c.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: My code's output]

Any cleaner approach to achieve a similar result is OK too!

Comment: The polar coordinate system uses `(angle:distance)` (so `(0.5:0)` is at a null distance from the origin at 0.5 degree!).

Comment: Dammit, I just had to use a comma instead of a double dot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, start chain = going below]

  \node[on chain] (a) {a};
  \node[on chain] (b) {b};
  \node[on chain] (c) {c};

  \node[anchor=west] at ($(a)!0.5!(b) + (1,0) $) (d) {d};
  \node[anchor=west] at ($(b)!0.5!(c) + (1,0) $) (e) {e};

  \draw[->] (a.east) -| (d.north);
  \draw[->] (d.south) |- ($(b.east)+(0,0.1)$);
  \draw[->] ($(b.east)-(0,0.1)$) -| (e.north);
  \draw[->] (e.south) |- (c.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks good with the toy example, but with my real case, I don't want to reach `north|south east` because the nodes are way bigger and closer to one another. I really want to target "just above|below" of `b.east`.

Comment: @nicoco Ooh... See if it is good for you now.

Comment: Yes it is, I was using polar coordinates without knowing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

with use of the `positioning` library and a `yshift`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1cm and 1cm
                        ]
  \node             (a) {a};
  \node[below right=of a] (d) {d};
  \node[below  left=of d] (b) {b};
  \node[below right=of b] (e) {e};
  \node[below  left=of e] (c) {c};

  \draw[->] (a) -| (d);
  \draw[->] (d) |- ([yshift=2] b.east);
  \draw[->] ([yshift=-2] b.east) -| (e);
  \draw[->] (e) |- (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```